# Spring Data REST - How to save parent entity with children at the same time

Tags: spring, rest, transactions, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Data REST to expose my entities and I want to be able to save (create & update) a parent entity along with its children at the same time.

Here are my entities :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "scenario")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Scenario extends AbstractAuditableEntity {

    @Id
    // Sequence name must be preceded by schema name.
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "scenarioIdSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "scenarioIdSeq", sequenceName = "scenario_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "SERIAL")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    // Used by JPA for optimistic locking
    protected int version;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "scenario")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    private Set<Action> actions = new HashSet<Action>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "action")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Action extends AbstractAuditableEntity {

    @Id
    // Sequence name must be preceded by schema name.
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "actionIdSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "actionIdSeq", sequenceName = "action_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "SERIAL")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    // Used by JPA for optimistic locking
    protected int version;

    @RestResource(rel = "action_scenario")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "scenario_id", columnDefinition = "BIGINT", nullable = false)
    private Scenario scenario;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "action")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    private Set<ActionParameter> parameters = new HashSet<ActionParameter>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "action_parameter")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class ActionParameter extends AbstractAuditableEntity {

    @Id
    // Sequence name must be preceded by schema name.
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "actionParamIdSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "actionParamIdSeq", sequenceName = "action_parameter_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "SERIAL")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    // Used by JPA for optimistic locking
    protected int version;

    @RestResource(rel = "parameter_action")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "action_id", columnDefinition = "BIGINT", nullable = false)
    private Action action;
}
```

So I want to be able to save (create & update) an entire scenario along with its actions and action parameters at the same time (within the same transaction).

What would be the best way to achieve that using Spring Data REST?

**Update 1:**

I've tried to use the cascade property as suggested, but now I'm getting this error :

> Could not write content: Detected multiple association links with same
>   relation type! Disambiguate association
>   @org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource(path=,
>   exported=true,
>   description=@org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.Description(value=),
>   rel=action_scenario)

Every relationship is already annotated with @RestResource(rel = "xxx") so I don't understand why I'm getting this error?!

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `cascade` property in your `@OneToMany` annotations:

I.e.:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "scenario", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)     
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<Action> actions = new HashSet<Action>();
}
```

This way, you can add `Action` instances to predefined `Set` and save them with your `Scenario`

```
Scenario scenario = new Scenario():
scenario.getActions.add(new Action);
scenarioRepository.save(scenario);
```

Comment: Tks for the answer... I've updated my question following your suggestion, but I'm getting a weird error now... maybe u have an idea why?